# Nodal DG method and limiters for hyperbolic conservation laws

Tags: discontinuous-galerkin

All the papers I have seen on DG methods for hyperbolic conservation laws together with limiters to compute discontinuous solutions make use of Taylor polynomial basis (Pk basis) or Legendre polynomials. In these cases, limiters have been developed. But if I want to use nodal basis on quadrilaterals/rectangles, then I have not seen any papers which develop limiters for this case. My attempts at writing a nodal DG code and extending the existing limiters in a "natural" way does not lead to accurate solutions.

So I am looking for any existing literature that uses nodal DG (Qk basis) on quadrilaterals and limiters to compute discontinuous solutions.

Thanks
praveen

Answer (score 4):

Hesthaven and Warburton's textbook "Nodal Discontinuous Galerkin Methods" has in chapter 5 descriptions of how to handle limiting. One interpretation of this is that through the Vandermonde matrix you can recover the Legendre polynomial coefficients directly from the nodal values and then use those limiters and then pass back to the nodal values.

Comment: Yes, that is one way to do it. But it involves additional work. Is this how everybody does limiting with nodal basis DG ?

Comment: I believe you can also interpret WENO schemes as nodal limiters, there's a section in ZJ Wang's compilation on it. Limiters are always going to involve additional work. Since Gibbs' phenomena manifests as oscillations, or "where coefficients for higher order polynomials decay slowly", it's pretty natural to do the limiting by modal values.

Comment: If I have to transform from nodal to modal to apply limiter, then I can as well start with a modal basis which avoids this additional work. I am using quadrature-based DG so I dont have any advantage in using nodal basis. I have seen one work which directly limits the solution in nodal form but this has been done only for Q1 case, see http://hal.inria.fr/inria-00072097

Answer (score 2):

Well, you say: "My attempts at writing a nodal DG code and extending the existing limiters in a "natural" way does not lead to accurate solutions."  So that may be a problem.  Limiters are going to affect accuracy.  Most limiters are going to reduce you to first order accurate, even at higher order.  The terrible fact is, the answer to this question is extremely problem/application dependent.  I would recommend checking out

http://www.overtureframework.org/banks/publications/sublinearContacts_JCP2008.pdf

http://www.mathematik.uni-dortmund.de/~kuzmin/dglim.pdf

The BDS limiter is a good multi-functioning limiter (see DOI:10.1016/j.jcp.2011.07.009), which can be used in both settings (nodal or modal) fairly easily.  As a general rule, I would say the first step in choosing a limiter is understanding very clearly what your high level goals are going to be.  For example, do you need to preserve positivity as well?  Are you after an optimal limiter, in terms of computational cycles, or are you aiming for the best accuracy you can find?  Do you need a robust solution, or is convergence order more important to you?  Are you going to be benchmarking against finite difference, finite volume, or spectral methods solutions, such that having too little numerical diffusion might actually cause you problems?  Understanding the setting is actually maybe the most important part of choosing a limiter.